# Problems with absl dependencies in TensorFlow print_selective_registration_header building

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to build //tensorflow/python/tools:print_selective_registration_header and get following output:

```
$ bazel build --copt="-DUSE_GEMM_FOR_CONV" tensorflow/python/tools:print_selective_registration_header
...
INFO: Analyzed target //tensorflow/python/tools:print_selective_registration_header (377 packages loaded, 24256 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
INFO: Deleting stale sandbox base /private/var/tmp/_bazel_glebdavydov/01d4cf1f69cd2606674d307a7a455e95/sandbox
ERROR: /Users/glebdavydov/Downloads/tensorflow-master/tensorflow/c/BUILD:372:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '//tensorflow/c:ops':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'tensorflow/c/ops.cc':
  'tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/absl/absl/strings/string_view.h'
  'tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/absl/absl/types/optional.h'
Target //tensorflow/python/tools:print_selective_registration_header failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 54.737s, Critical Path: 13.10s
INFO: 4 processes: 4 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that issue by installing version of bazel corresponding to this [build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations).